# Codekit compile sass with browser compatibility

Tags: codekit

when I use code kit, I cannot compile my sass to have cross browser compatibility.

What I mean is that if I write `transition` I want code kit to compile that into this:

```
transition: all 0.25s
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s
```

Code kit does not do this. Instead this is all that is outputted is this:

```
transition: all 0.25s
```

I have looked in the sass and css settings, and I have found nothing to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to add auto-prefixing, you simply need to go to special language tools under the Languages tab. Then check the run autoprefixer button. Save your work again and boom, you're good to go.